# VNC connection over public IP is not working

Tags: vnc, vncserver, tightvnc

I installed TightVNC. I enabled port forwarding and port was opened, I checked it here https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

TightVNC added itself to Firewall exception. TightVNC server was running, I disabled Windows 10 firewall and router firewall.

I tried to connect via one laptop, then via another phone but it was not working.

I tried everything that I could find online but nothing is working. Connection via local network is working just fine, but via public IP is not working. Basically it's: my-public-ip::my-port

Can someone help me?

Comment: are you testing this from inside the LAN? if so, you will need a router that supports Hairpin NAT. most home/soho-grade routers do not.

Comment: I'm doing this over WiFi

Comment: right but is it YOUR wifi, on the same internet connection as the VNC server? thats the circumstance when you need Hairpinning/Nat_Loopback. if you are on the same network as the server, but you want to test public connectivity by connecting to your external address, it will fail if your router doesn't support and is configured for hairpinning. I know, it's far from optimal, I agree.

Comment: So my router doesn't support Hairpin/NAT? I looked everywhere for that option, it's not there

Comment: yeah, that's likely. generally only enterprise kit does. You'll prolly have to test from a friends place or the coffee shop down the way. Let us know if it works!

Comment: perhaps a remote forward via ssh will work to another public IP you can log into. Then from anywhere else, access that public IP which magically lets you connect.